# Call recently added script from another script

Tags: vbscript

As soon as the file is added to script folder it is detected by this code.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE " _
    & "Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and " _
    & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " _
    & "'Win32_Directory.Name=""c:\\\\scripts""'")
Do
    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    Wscript.Echo objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent
Loop
```

I want to execute VBScript as soon as it is added to script folder from this VBScript. How to do that? Getting the name of the file that is added to script folder and then executing that VBScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this modified script :

```
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding !" & VbCrLF &_
    CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,"There is an existing proceeding !"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else 
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE " _
    & "Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and " _
    & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " _
    & "'Win32_Directory.Name=""d:\\\\scripts""'")

    Do
        Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
        Call DoWithName(objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent)
    Loop
End if
' --------------------------------------
Sub DoWithName( strPartComp)
    Dim Title,arrFileName,Question,ws
    Title = "Execute vbscript"
    set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    arrFileName = Split( strPartComp, """")
    If True Or UBound(arrFileName) > 0 Then
        Wscript.Echo strPartComp _
        & vbNewLine & UBound( arrFileName) _
        & vbNewLine & "[" & arrFileName( 0)  & "]" _
        & vbNewLine & "[" & arrFileName( 1)  & "]" _
        & vbNewLine & "[" & arrFileName( 2)  & "]" _
        & vbNewLine & DblQuote(ShowAbsolutePath(arrFileName(1)))
    End If
    Question = MsgBox("Did you want to execute this vbscript : " & DblQuote(ShowAbsolutePath(arrFileName(1))),vbYesNo+vbQuestion,Title)
    If Question = vbYes Then
        ws.run DblQuote(ShowAbsolutePath(arrFileName(1)))
    Else
    End if
End Sub
' --------------------------------------
Function ShowAbsolutePath( strPath)
    Dim fso
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ShowAbsolutePath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName( strPath)
End Function
' --------------------------------------
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
' --------------------------------------
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
' --------------------------------------
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function  
' --------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line of code with the code you want executed any time a new file is detected: `Wscript.Echo objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent`. For instance, next code snippet shows a possible approach (and that's why there is wide `Echo` output, wider than necessary...):

```
''''(unchanged code above)
Do
    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    ''''Wscript.Echo objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent
    Call DoWithName( objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent)
Loop

Sub DoWithName( strPartComp)
  Dim arrFileName
  arrFileName = Split( strPartComp, """")
  If True Or UBound(arrFileName) > 0 Then
    Wscript.Echo strPartComp _
    & vbNewLine & UBound( arrFileName) _
    & vbNewLine & "[" & arrFileName( 0)  & "]" _
    & vbNewLine & "[" & arrFileName( 1)  & "]" _
    & vbNewLine & "[" & arrFileName( 2)  & "]" _
    & vbNewLine & ShowAbsolutePath( arrFileName( 1))
  End If
End Sub

Function ShowAbsolutePath( strPath)
   Dim fso
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   ShowAbsolutePath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName( strPath)
End Function
```

Note that

- the `ShowAbsolutePath( arrFileName( 1))` returns the name of the file that is added to script folder; now you could
- check whether it's a valid `.vbs` file name, and if so, launch it combining any Windows Script Host engine (`wscript.exe` or `cscript.exe`) in either

  - [Run Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx) or
  - [Exec Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a(v=vs.84).aspx).